# What's the difference of "co_await other_co" and "other_co.resume"?

Tags: c++, c++20, coroutine

The following code doesn't work as my expectation.

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <coroutine>
#include <vector>

struct symmetic_awaitable
{
    std::coroutine_handle<> _next_h;

    symmetic_awaitable(std::coroutine_handle<> h) : _next_h(h) {}

    constexpr bool await_ready() const noexcept { return false; }

    std::coroutine_handle<> await_suspend(std::coroutine_handle<>) const noexcept
    {
        return _next_h;
    }

    constexpr void await_resume() const noexcept {}
};

struct return_object : std::coroutine_handle<>
{
    struct promise_type
    {
        return_object get_return_object()
        {
            return std::coroutine_handle<promise_type>::from_promise(*this);
        }

        std::suspend_always initial_suspend() noexcept { return {}; }
        std::suspend_always final_suspend() noexcept { return {}; }
        void return_void() {}
        void unhandled_exception() {}
    };

    return_object(std::coroutine_handle<promise_type> h) : std::coroutine_handle<>(h) {}
};

std::vector<return_object> co_list;

return_object fa()
{
    std::cout << "fa1" << std::endl;
    co_await symmetic_awaitable(co_list[1]);
    std::cout << "fa2" << std::endl;
    co_return;
}

return_object fb()
{
    std::cout << "fb1" << std::endl;
    co_await symmetic_awaitable(co_list[2]);
    std::cout << "fb2" << std::endl;
    co_await std::suspend_always{};
    std::cout << "fb3" << std::endl;
    co_return;
}

return_object fc()
{
    std::cout << "fc1" << std::endl;
    co_await symmetic_awaitable(co_list[1]);
    std::cout << "fc2" << std::endl;
    co_return;
}

int main()
{
    auto a = fa();
    auto b = fb();
    auto c = fc();

    co_list.push_back(a);
    co_list.push_back(b);
    co_list.push_back(c);

    a.resume();
    std::cout << "end" << std::endl;

    a.destroy();
    b.destroy();
    c.destroy();
}
```

I think the output will be

```
fa1
fb1
fc1
fb2
fa2
end
```

But the actual output is

```
fa1
fb1
fc1
fb2
end
```

Then I replace all `co_await symmetic_awaitable(co_list[i])` with `co_list[i].resume`. The ouput is very strange

```
fa1
fb1
fc1
fb1
fc1
.....  // the following is infinite loop of "fb1 fc1"
.....
.....
```

The C++20 coroutine shadow too many details, such that the code can't work normally as my expectation unless I know them all clearly.
Here are my questions after I read cppreference:

### 1. What's the defference of "caller" and "resumer" ?

a call `b.resume()`, then a is the resumer or caller of b ?

### 2. What's the exact meanning of "suspended" ?

a call `b.resume()`, then a is suspended or running? a resume b through `co_await`, then a is suspended or running ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If a function is a coroutine, it can only become suspended in one of the following ways:

1. When the coroutine starts, if the promise initially suspends.
2. When a `co_await` expression (or equivalent, like `co_yield`) is directly invoked.
3. When the coroutine `co_return`s, if the promise finally suspends.

*Nothing else* can cause a coroutine to become suspended. The "co" in "coroutine" represents cooperative multitasking. That means there's no multitasking unless the function(s) involved *cooperate*. Explicitly.

Your assumptions about how you expect your code to work seem to suggest that you believe that coroutines have some kind of execution stack. That when `await_suspend` is called, the current coroutine gets put onto a stack that will be poped when the coroutine handle you returned finishes in some way. And therefore, when you invoke `co_await std::suspend_always{};` this will resume the previously suspended coroutine.

None of that is true. Not unless you *build* that machinery yourself.

The coroutine system does exactly and *only* what you tell it to do.

The call stack immediately after calling `a.resume()` looks like this:

```
main()
fa()
```

When `fa` suspends and resumes `fb`, it now looks like this:

```
main()
fb()
```

`fa` is *gone*. You suspended it. It is no longer on the call stack. And it will only ever be resumed if you *explicitly* ask to resume it.

If you want `fa`'s suspension into `fb` to mean that `fa` will be continued after `fb` finishes, then you must *build* that into your coroutine machinery. It doesn't just happen; it's your responsibility to make it happen.

Your `await_suspend` code needs to take the handle it is given (which refers to `fa`) and store it in a place where, when `fb` is finished, it can resume `fa`. This will typically be in `fb`'s promise object, so that `final_suspend` can resume it (typically passing along the data generated by `fb`). Remember: the final-suspend point will `co_await` on whatever the promise's `final_suspend` returns, so you can just return the handle of the coroutine you want to resume.

> What's the defference of "caller" and "resumer" ?

I don't know what that means. I suspect you are asking what the difference is between `co_await`ing on something and directly calling `coroutine_handle::resume` function.

As previously indicated, outside of the initial and final suspend points, *only* `co_await` (or equivalent) expressions can cause a coroutine to suspend. Calling `resume` on a handle is like you called into the middle of a function. It works just like any other function call; it goes onto the stack and so forth.

Having `co_await` resume a coroutine is different. When `await_suspend` returns a coroutine handle, this *replaces* your coroutine with the resumed coroutine on the call stack. That's the whole point of suspending the coroutine.